# After upgrade cordova version 6.4.0 to cordova 9.0.0 android platform build gets fail with error

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have upgrade cordova version 6.4.0 to cordova 9.0.0 and facing issue on android build command.
Also updated cordova-android version for cordova-android 6.1.0 to cordova-android 7.1.3
I can not understand what exactly error is about can any one please help me out regarding this error.

Error log:

[image]

Comment: Try removing the plugins and re-installing them again.

Comment: I already removed and added plugins many times.
Can you suggest me what error is about